# Multiple series - JSON - chart series are same despite different call of fields

Tags: json, highcharts, series

I need help on this. I have managed to create a chart I have obtained from a source and adapt it to my own data, but even two different series are defined, the data are taken only from one field and are the same. Where is the mistake?

Code that is used in principle:

```
function populatechart(pallino) {
  console.log(pallino)
  var misure = pallino.feeds;
  var serie = [
    []
  ];

for (let i = 0; i < misure.length; i++) {
  
    serie[i] = []
    serie[i][0] = misure[i].created_at
    serie[i][1] = parseFloat(misure[i].field3)
    serie[i][2] = parseFloat(misure[i].field8)

  }

  serie.forEach(function(point) {
    point[0] = Date.parse(point[0])
    
  });
```

```
series: [{
      type: 'line',
      name: 'PM2.5',
      data: serie
     },{
      type: 'column',
      name: 'Axel',
      data: serie
      
      
    }],
```

... I have not more idea, how to go on ...

Comment: In the meantime I have found my own solution - TXS for viewing!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.